# POSTing data with one to many relationship using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

When Posting data with one to many relationship using Thymeleaf, I want to save form site with dropdown list (nomclient) from table produit

**Entity Model**

```
 @Entity

 public class Produit implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="produit")
    private List<Site> listSites=new ArrayList<Site>();
    ...
```

**Entity Model - Produit**

```
public class Site implements Serializable {
  ...
  @JoinColumn(name = "refProduit")
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Produit produit;
  ...
```

**Controller site**

```
@Controller
public class SiteController {

  private SiteRepository siteRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value="/save2",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String save2(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("site") Site site, BindingResult result) {
     if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "formProduit";
       }  else{                                                                     
            siteRepository.save(site);               //line55    

      return "confirmationsite";
      }}

...
```

**ERROR**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.web.SiteController.save2(SiteController.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: if I see that correct. you should autowire `SiteRepository`.

Comment: thanks @Patrick for your reply , can you tell me how i autowire SiteRepository please

Comment: you already have `private SiteRepository siteRepository;` just put `@Autowired` in the line above

Comment: i had this error  @Patrik "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "produit.nomclient" (confirmationsite:23)" " Property or field 'nomclient' cannot be found on null"

Comment: data of site is saved  but dropdown list (nomclient of table produit) in form site is not saved (empty)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to inject the Repository into the controller. Add `@Inject` on top of the `siteRepository`.

```
@Controller
public class SiteController {

  @Inject
  private SiteRepository siteRepository;
```